# Bootstrap modal backdrop z-index between an element and a descendant of the element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[Question at the bottom]

### Background of Bootstrap versions

Bootstrap 3.3.2, dark modal overlay (`.modal-backdrop`) is put under `.modal`.

Since 3.3.4, it is put under `<body>`.

Some element z-index becomes impossible with 3.3.4.

---

### Background of my issue

I have made something with modal on 3.3.2.  Now I need to upgrade Bootstrap, to 4.x, but let me illustrate the issue with 3.3.4.

The page is a fixed positioned nav.  Clicking on a button shows a modal.

Nav needs to be under backdrop.  Modal on top of backdrop.  So

**The desired stack order is**

## modal > backdrop > nav

modal is within nav in HTML

```
<.nav>
    <.modal></.modal>
</.nav>
```

---

### With 3.3.2

where backdrop is appended (by bootstrap) under modal, I have done the desired order.

```
<.modal>
    <.modal-backdrop></...>
    <.modal-dialog></...>
</.modal>
```

### [Good, DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BPgjOp)

[image: 3.3.2, correct stack]

---

### With 3.3.4

```
<body>
    <div>
        <.modal>
            <.modal-dialog></...>
        </.modal>
    </div>

    <.modal-backdrop></...>
</body>
```

when nav is below backdrop, everything in nav, including modal, is below backdrop.  It seems impossible to set the stack order of anything to be between nav and a decendant of nav.

### [Bad, DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pZXgBV)

[image: 3.3.4]

[image: 3.3.4]

---

I know that things are easy if modal is put as a child of `<body>`, but this structural change will cause other implementation problems (nav is a module, things outside nav does not know the content of modal).

---

To pull backdrop to under modal by js is ok, but causing other problems:
1.  Flickering on the button upon z-index change.
2.  Cannot close by clicking backdrop.
See button `nav 3 Open modal` of the 3.3.4 demo.

---

### Question

With modal still under nav, on newer Bootstrap, how to make the desired stack order?

---

### References

1. [Bootstrap Release v3.3.4](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v3.3.4): contains #15881
2. [Bootstrap issue #15881](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/15881): The backdrop will now again be appended to the body and not the .modal container.